# Django - Error when I filter my form field's queryset

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-urls

I created a form and view (FBV) to add new model. I overrided form's `__init__` but now when I try to access my view it raise an error ***CreationForm' object has no attribute 'get'***

My view :

```
def Creation(request):
    user = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user

    #   POST METHOD
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreationForm(request.POST)   
        form.user = user    
        if form.is_valid():
            sheet = form.save()
            return redirect("sheet_detail", pk=sheet.id)

    form = CreationForm(initial={'user': request.user})
    return render(request, "jde/creation_form.html", context={"form": form})
```

My form :

```
class CreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreationForm, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["contest"].queryset = Contest.objects.filter(active=True)

    class Meta:
        ...
```

Comment: its because you are using `self.fields[`. maybe override the get_form method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being raised because you're passing `self` to the call to `super().__init()`. Removing it should solve your problem.

```
class CreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["contest"].queryset = Contest.objects.filter(active=True)

    class Meta:
        ...
```